# Quick way to solve simple probability questions like these?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Two dice are rolled. What is the chance of rolling at least ONE six? (The answer is $\frac{11}{36}$.)

My solutions manual has a very elaborate table drawing method and I don't want to do that. I need something more quick. (I could have drawn the table in the time it took me to answer this question and so forth, but I'm keen on learning new methods!)

Comment: The number of outcomes with at least one six is: both six (1) + first six and second not six (5) plus second six and first not six (5)= 11.

Comment: 1 - P(no 6) = 1 - (5/6)^2 = 11/36.

Comment: Also P(6 on 1st) + P(no 6 on 1st and 6 on 2nd) = 1/6 + 5/6*1/6 = 11/36.

Comment: Actually not obviously a duplicate, as it asks for a method (which none of the current answers explicitly provides, though they use three slightly different approaches) while the other question is about a particular case. One wonders what the _very elaborate table drawing method_ is and cannot help suspecting that it is probably a simple 6×6 table showing the 11 cases. In that case it would have been hard to provide a method tailored to the questioner’s personal insights at the time of asking and to the unstated range of _questions like this_.

Answer (score 1):

Getting at least one six can be done by the first die getting a six or the second die getting the six. So we might try to double the probability of one die getting a six. However, this double-counts the case where *both* dice get a six. Therefore we subtract that probability. We get the final answer

$$P=2\cdot\frac 16-\left(\frac 16\right)^2=\frac{11}{36}$$

Is that fast enough?

Comment: Where is my logic going wrong? I'm too dumb for this..The first dice to roll a six: 1/6. The second dice to roll a six: 1/6. Ergo, 2/12 = 1/6...

Comment: $\frac 16+\frac 16=\frac 26$, not $\frac 2{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

We consider two cases:

1. we have exactly one six:

   Since two dices differ, there is $2\times5$ ways for that
2. we have two 6s:

   it would be just in $1$ way.

Over all, the probability would be $\dfrac{2\times5+1}{6\times6}=\dfrac{11}{36}$

Answer (score 1):

The probability that at least one six is rolled is the complement of the probability that no sixes are rolled.  The probability of not rolling a six is $5/6$.  Thus, the probability that no sixes are rolled is

$$P(\text{no sixes}) = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 = \frac{25}{36}$$

Hence, the probability that at least one six is rolled is

$$P(\text{at least one six}) = 1 - P(\text{no sixes}) = 1 - \frac{25}{36} = \frac{11}{36}$$